# Вывод значений с двумерного массива

Tags: python, массивы

Есть изображение 10х10 пикселов, мне надо считать информацию о цвете каждого пикселя и записью в текстовый файл. Но перед этим я захотел просто проверить, как ОНО будет работать:

```
#! usr/bin/env python
# -*-coding: utf-8 -*-
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("python.jpg")
pix = im.load()
x,y = 0,0
for x in xrange(10):
    for y in xrange(10):
        print pix[x,y]
```

Цвета выводит, но - выводит их вот так:

```
(255, 209, 63)
(255, 204, 61)
(255, 207, 69)
(250, 202, 74)
(241, 199, 81)
(255, 230, 119)
(96, 150, 196)
(58, 120, 171)
............
```

А мне надо, чтобы выводил матрицей размером, как и изображение (10х10), примерно так:

```
(255, 209, 63)(255, 204, 61)(255, 207, 69).... 
(250, 202, 74)(241, 199, 81)(255, 230, 119)....
(96, 150, 196)(58, 120, 171)....
......
```

Как мне это исправить, и собственно, а как дальше поступить, чтобы записал данные в файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что будет, если строку завершить запятой?

```
   print pix[x,y],
```

Если я все правильно помню, оно самое и будет.
Правда, после каждого ряда надо печатать смену строки.

Comment: а вот про запятую - забыл!
а,как теперь все это записать в файл - это главный вопрос

Answer (score 4):

```
#! usr/bin/env python
# -*-coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("python.jpg")
pix = im.load()
result = ''
for x in xrange(10):
  for y in xrange(10):
    result += str(pix[x, y])
  result += '\n'

with open('result.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(result)
```

Например такое решение... Но думаю можно придумать и что-то более элегантное...

Comment: вот не могу разобраться с этим,а если надо что бы в строке было не 10 значений,а например по 3?
кстати,спасибо - работает

Comment: поэтому решение не элегантно ) посмотри на join может с ним можно что придумать

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите полностью контролировать вывод, то можно использовать sys.stdout.write() вместо print.

Вывод в файл с print делается так:
f = open(...) #открыть файл
print(1, file = f) #записать "1" в файл